# How can i check hardware inventory on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a network with a 60 nodes (all linux based). Ubuntu distribution 14.04. Now our managers need to create a report about pc parts that need a replacement and asked me to give them an information list or a report. I found some 3rd party program like this [hardware inventory software](http://www.softinventive.com/hardware-inventory/) and [this](http://www.lansweeper.com/). They dont check all pc`s though. Can i write a script or do it other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **to create a report about pc parts ... Can [I] write a script**

Yes, you can write a script to obtain information from the /proc filesystem

```
cd /proc; cat cpuinfo meminfo scsi/scsi ...
```

You can also use commands that report on hardware

```
lscpu; lscpi; lsusb; ... lshw; ...
```

You can of course use something like ssh to remotely execute a script on 60 Ubuntu 14 PCs that you have administrative access to. You can then collate the results centrally and produce some sort of inventory report on hardware.

Whether this will help you meet your goals depends on your precise goals.

Answer (score 1):

Try new [Linux-Hardware.org](https://linux-hardware.org/)'s HW Probe Tool: https://github.com/linuxhw/hw-probe

Use `hw-probe -get-group` to get your group `ID` and use it to mark probes of all your computers (add `-group ID` option):

```
hw-probe -all -upload -group ID
```

Then you can enter your group `ID` here to filter your computers: https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?view=computers

Use [this Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxhw/hw-probe/) in order to probe your hardware on Ubuntu or any other Linux distribution without the need to install anything on your host except Docker.

Probe example: https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?probe=0b29192f95

Also you can import all your probes from the database for offline use and create local index by the `-import DIR` option (generates/updates index to `DIR`):

```
hw-probe -import DIR
```